# Multi-bitrate encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, wowza

How can I generate multiple versions of the same video file at different bitrates that are properly key-frame aligned? Is it posible with ffmpeg?

Here is an article with example  http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?192-Encoding-Suggestions-for-Video-on-Demand

The article says that "Multi-birate encoding has not worked using ffmpeg".  Is it right?

Answer (score 4):

use two-pass encoding, process first pass with the lowest resolution and then encode again each resolution with pass=2 which will use stats generated with first pass. this will guarantee keyframes to be in excactly the same places.

Answer (score 3):

You should use no-scenecut, keyint and min-keyint options. Set the keyint and min-keyint options to the same values.
For example:
keyint=70:min-keyint=70:no-scenecut